# Tooltip cut off by div container

Tags: html, css, tooltip, positioning

I've searched this a lot and have not found, or at least I haven't been able to implement,  the  proper answer.

I am building a site in which I have a scrolling div with an image. I am placing tooltips over certain parts of the image, but when they are activated, the tooltips are cut off by the constraints of the div.

Working example: http://navalage.neocities.org/menu1-test.html

It is in the bottom menu. The stage tooltip appears inside of the div, and I have the others outside as an example of what I want them to do.

Hopefully someone can help, thank you!

CSS is

```
<style>
body {
background-color: black;
}
.div {font-family: san-serif;}




/* Tooltip container */
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid ;
    border-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);  
/* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
}
/* Tooltip text */
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 294px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px dashed white;
    font-family: arial;
    /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    -mox-transition: 1;
    z-index:33;
}

/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index:34;
}

</style>
```

HTML is;

```
<div style="z-index: 2; overflow: scroll; max-width: 240px; background-color: black; margin-left: 84px; margin-top: -54px; width: 213px; height: 50px; -moz-transform: skew(1.5deg);">







<!-- Stage -->

<div class="tooltip" style="z-index: 3; margin-top:2px; margin-left: 0px; width: 35; height: 44px;">
<span style="margin-left: -84px; margin-top: -0px; z-index: 999;" class="tooltiptext"><b><u>Stage</b></u>: This is where you go to battle the enemy in the main story line (there isnt much of one).</span>
</div>

<img src="IMAGES/mainmenu.jpg" style="height:50px; margin-left: -5px; margin-top: -47px; -moz-transform: skew(-1.5deg);">

<!-- END -->

<!-- Fleet -->

<div class="tooltip" style="top: 489px; left: 130px; width: 35; height: 44px;">
<span style="margin-left: -120px; margin-top: -110px;" class="tooltiptext"><b><u>Fleet</b></u>: Here you can set up your base defence when somebody is attacking. You can also repair your ships and check on the current status of any fleets on a mission.</span>
</div>

<!-- END -->

<!-- Alliance -->

<div class="tooltip" style="position: absolute; top: 489px; left: 168px; width: 35; height: 44px;">
<span style="margin-left: -158px; margin-top: -91px;" class="tooltiptext"><b><u>Alliance</b></u>: Acces your alliance for donations, Elite Challenges (EC), Alliance fleet, Collect Supplies, Alliance War, and alliance technology.</span>
</div>

<!-- END -->


<!-- Item -->

<div class="tooltip" style="position: absolute; top: 489px; left: 206px; width: 35; height: 44px;">
<span style="margin-left: -196px; margin-top: -53px;" class="tooltiptext"><b><u>Item</b></u>: Acces your items, as well as the shop, and flash sale.</span>
</div>

<!-- END -->

<!-- Mail -->

<div class="tooltip" style="position: absolute; top: 489px; left: 244px; width: 35; height: 44px;">
<span style="margin-left: -234px; margin-top: -91px;" class="tooltiptext"><b><u>Mail</b></u>: This is where you recieve mail from system, friends, alliance leaders, escort, scout reports, and attack and defense reports. </span>
</div>

<!-- END -->


<!-- NEXT -->
<div class="tooltip" style="position: absolute; top: 489px; left: 282px; width: 25; height: 44px;">
<span style="margin-left: -272px; margin-top: 0px;" class="tooltiptext">Go to the next menu page
<a href="menu2.html">
<button>
Next</button>
</a>

</span>
</div>

<!-- END -->






</div>
```

Comment: Please share the code or a provide us a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your css in in this div and span

```
<div class="tooltip" style="z-index: 3;margin-top:2px;margin-left: 0px;width: 35;height: 44px;position: absolute;">
<span style="margin-left: -84px;margin-top: -72px;/* z-index: 999; */" class="tooltiptext"><b><u>Stage</u></b>: This is where you go to battle the enemy in the main story line (there isnt much of one).</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It's still not bringing the tooltip outside of the div though.

Comment: I have done it with the same. Just replace you old DIV to this DIV. It will work surly

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing this as a working result. This places the item outside of my div, which immediately makes them useless. They're in the div so they can scroll with the image. The goal is to leave the hoverable content inside of the div, while making the tooltip popup appear outside the constraints of the div.

Comment: You said you have it working, can you provide an example?

Comment: I'm think I'm gonna be able to find a work around with x-tooltip. https://github.com/x-tag/tooltip/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Still having the same issue. Can't take the child element out of the parent element. My abilities are severely limited, but I'm still trying to find a proper workaround without using js